# How to kill all vpns on switch user Mint 17.2

Tags: linux-mint, users, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm using mint 17.2 cinnamon. I'm not particular about the method, just want it to stop all vpn connections (openvpn, listed in network manager) when I switch users or logout.

nmcli doesn't provide a "nmcli con down all" type function, so I think I am looking at `pkill vpn`.

"pkill vpn" works when run manually, but requires sudo. I have tried adding it in /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99zz_killVPN, but no luck. I saw an article on doing this with lightdm, but mint doesn't use that by default. Also, I assume that when you switch users, the previous user is put in suspend, but I haven't been able to find anything to confirm that. Anyone know what exactly happens to the non-active users?